# Understanding native code of SocketAddress that changed from JDK8 to JDK11

Tags: c, sockets, ip

[net_util_md.h](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/solaris/native/java/net/net_util_md.h) from JDK8 had the following code for a socket address:

```
#ifdef AF_INET6

#define SOCKADDR        union { \
                            struct sockaddr_in him4; \
                            struct sockaddr_in6 him6; \
                        }

#define SOCKADDR_LEN    (ipv6_available() ? sizeof(SOCKADDR) : \
                         sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))

#else

#define SOCKADDR        union { struct sockaddr_in him4; }
#define SOCKADDR_LEN    sizeof(SOCKADDR)

#endif
```

[net_util_md.h](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/net_util_md.h) from JDK11 now has the following code for a socket address:

```
typedef union {
    struct sockaddr     sa;
    struct sockaddr_in  sa4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 sa6;
} SOCKETADDRESS;
```

So in JDK8 I could cast a reference to `SOCKADDR` to `struck sockaddr *` and compare with the following C code:

```
int sockaddr_cmp(struct sockaddr *x, struct sockaddr *y)
{
#define CMP(a, b) if (a != b) return a < b ? -1 : 1

    CMP(x->sa_family, y->sa_family);

    if (x->sa_family == AF_UNIX) {
        struct sockaddr_un *xun = (void*)x, *yun = (void*)y;
        int r = strcmp(xun->sun_path, yun->sun_path);
        if (r != 0)
            return r;
    } else if (x->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *xin = (void*)x, *yin = (void*)y;
        CMP(ntohl(xin->sin_addr.s_addr), ntohl(yin->sin_addr.s_addr));
        CMP(ntohs(xin->sin_port), ntohs(yin->sin_port));
    } else if (x->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *xin6 = (void*)x, *yin6 = (void*)y;
        int r = memcmp(xin6->sin6_addr.s6_addr, yin6->sin6_addr.s6_addr, sizeof(xin6->sin6_addr.s6_addr));
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
         }
        CMP(ntohs(xin6->sin6_port), ntohs(yin6->sin6_port));
        CMP(xin6->sin6_flowinfo, yin6->sin6_flowinfo);
        CMP(xin6->sin6_scope_id, yin6->sin6_scope_id);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

#undef CMP
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do the same with the new `SOCKETADDRESS` from JDK11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So in JDK8 I could cast the `SOCKADDR` to `struck sockaddr *` [sic]

I presume you mean you could cast *pointers to* `SOCKADDR` as you describe.  That would be reasonable, but casting a `SOCKADDR` itself would not be.

Good news: you can still do much the same as before.  A `SOCKETADDRESS *` may safely be cast to `struct sockaddr *`, and two `struct sockaddr *` values obtained that way may be compared via your existing function.  The function presented is at least as valid for that case as it was for the JDK 8 case. (Which is not *completely* valid either way, but that's a separate matter).

Comment: Thanks @John. Yeah, I mean I can cast a *reference* to `SOCKADDR` to `struct sockaddr *`. I'm confused because the new union has 3 fields instead of 2. How can they be equivalent for comparison?

Comment: @CCCoder, the storage for all members of a union overlaps, no matter how many members there are.  Your whole approach depends on that.

Comment: As you can see I'm a newbie in C, trying to maintain some code. I know, that's dangerous. I had no idea that an union is an overlap. So a *Union* just provides synonyms in terms of type for the same data, correct?

Comment: Some people do think of it that way, @CCCoder, but it's not technically correct.  There are several subtleties here, but the most correct way to think about it is that a union provides storage for objects of different types, one at a time.  Only under certain circumstances and to a limited extent is it technically allowed to access the object currently stored within via a member with a different type than the one used to store it.

Comment: Got you! Thanks so much! Love C, it is so straightforward :P